# Как настроить задний фон у графика?

Tags: javascript, диаграммы

Есть график на amchart4. Выглядит он вот так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
`https://codepen.io/vitalytalyzin/pen/wNaxyN?editors=0010`
```

С построением осей и первого уровня столбцов проблем не возникает, но вот задний слой, тот что полупрозначный, никак не поддается реализации.

Пытался сделать с помощью стеков, но не получается соединить их в единый слой. Готовых решений библиотека не предоставляет.

Может быть кто-то реализовывал такой график?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Удалось реализовать следующим образом:

1. Создаем вторую серию с нужными нам характеристиками
2. Разрешаем столбцам вставать друг за другом с помощью clustered:
   false
3. Выводим нужный нам столбец на первый уровень через zIndex
4. Устанавливаем столбцам второго уровня ширину в 100% columns.width =
   100%

Финальный результат:

```
`https://codepen.io/vitalytalyzin/pen/wNaxyN?editors=0010`
```